# How to group data by 7 days in db2 select query without using week keyword

Tags: db2

I am select data from a table with different timestamps and I need to group the data by 7 days intervals without using the week keyword.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and exact result expected?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `week` "keyword" (function actually)?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the DAYS function and divide it by 7 like

GROUP BY DAYS(my_dt_column) / 7

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000789.html